# ¿Como abrir un modal que se encuentra fuera de una funcion, jquery?

Tags: jquery

tengo la siguiente función que abre un modal

```
$$('.page[data-page=selecciondireccion] [data-action=change-quantity]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this).closest('.swipeout');
    var el_product_quantity = el.find('.product-quantity');
    var product_unit_price = el.find('.item-after').data('unit-price');
    var el_product_amount = el.find('.product-amount'); 
    myApp.prompt('Cantidad', 
  function(value) {
    if(value > 0) {
                el_product_quantity.text(value);
                el_product_amount.text(product_unit_price * value);
            }
            updateAmount();
  }
);
    myApp.swipeoutClose(el);
});
```

y genero un listado de productos dinamicamente de esta forma:

```
 $$("#btn-verCarrito").click(function(e){
    myApp.showTab("#historialCarrito", true);  
     //Agregando la lista de productos
     var listProductos = $('.products-list');
     $.each(valCarrito, function(i){
            $('<li/>').addClass('swipeout')
                .append($('<div/>').addClass('swipeout-content item-content')
                            .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-media')
                                .append('<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/v7vadq9iitpheo4/iphone-7-plus-black.png?raw=1" alt="Apple iPhone 7 Plus (Black)" width="55" height="75" />'))
                            .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-inner')
                                .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-title-row')
                                        .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-title').text('Contenido dinamico'))
                                        .append('<div class="item-after" data-unit-price="'+valCarrito[i].cantProducto+'">Q<span class="product-amount">'+0+'</span></div>')
                                        )
                                .append('<div class="item-subtitle">Color: Black | Storage: 128 GB</div>')
                                .append($('<div/>').addClass('item-text')
                                            .append($('<div/>').addClass('chip chip-small').append('<div class="chip-label"><span class="product-quantity">'+valCarrito[i].cantProducto+'</span></div>')))
                                    )
                        )
                .append($('<div/>').addClass('swipeout-actions swipeout-actions-right')
                        .append('<a href="#" class="swipeout-action bg-amber" data-action="change-quantity"><i class="swipeout-action-icon fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="swipeout-action-label">Cambiar&nbsp;Cantidad</span></a>'))

            .appendTo(listProductos);
            updateAmount();
     });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

El detalle es en esta parte del codigo:

```
.append('<a href="#" class="swipeout-action bg-amber" data-action="change-quantity"><i class="swipeout-action-icon fa fa-pencil"></i><span class="swipeout-action-label">Cambiar&nbsp;Cantidad</span></a>'))
```

al darle clic acá debe abrir el modal que se encuentra en la funcion que anteriormente di. Deberia mandar a llamar a la funcion con esta parte: `data-action="change-quantity"` pero con el contenido dinamico no manda abrir el modalo, ahora si todo lo agrego estaticamente desde el html si ejecuta el modal.

Gracias.

Comment: Si usas Jquery bastarai con usar la función modal y darle la instrucción: `$("#IDDETUMODAL").moda("show")`

Comment: También puedes utilizar $('#modal').toggle(); en caso quieras abrirlo y cerrarlo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al crear dinámicamente el html no reconoce el evento `click` llamado. Para eso, deberías pasarle un tercer parámetro al [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para que este funcione.

Algo como lo siguiente:

```
$$('.products-list').on('click', '.page[data-page=selecciondireccion] [data-action=change-quantity]', function(e) { ...
// el .products-list es un html estático y padre del elemento que vas a agregar
```

Dentro de lo que has realizado quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
$$('.products-list').on('click', '.page[data-page=selecciondireccion] [data-action=change-quantity]', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var el = $(this).closest('.swipeout');
    var el_product_quantity = el.find('.product-quantity');
    var product_unit_price = el.find('.item-after').data('unit-price');
    var el_product_amount = el.find('.product-amount'); 
    myApp.prompt('Cantidad', 
  function(value) {
    if(value > 0) {
                el_product_quantity.text(value);
                el_product_amount.text(product_unit_price * value);
            }
            updateAmount();
  }
);
    myApp.swipeoutClose(el);
});
```

---

#### Nota:

Esto ocurre porque al momento de ejecutar el evento `click` no existe dentro del DOM, y luego al crear dinámicamente el resto, no lo va a reconocer.

Answer (score -1):

en el momento que quieres que se ejecute el modal en la documentacion te lo dice claro cuando sea que quieras activar el modal solo lo tienes que llamar asi

`$("#mymodal").modal("show")`